# Split sentences by comma using the stanford nlp api?

Tags: java, parsing, split, stanford-nlp

Is there a way to split sentences by comma, using the stanford nlp api?

Here's my code:

```
 public void splitSentences(String paragraph, List<String> sentences){
    Reader reader = new StringReader(paragraph);
    DocumentPreprocessor dp = new DocumentPreprocessor(reader);
    for (List<HasWord> sentence : dp) {
       String sentenceString = Sentence.listToString(sentence);
       sentences.add(sentenceString.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: If you just want to split by comma, why don't just do `paragraph.split(",")`?

Comment: yes that what i exactly did ; thnx jushalf